# Making a struct thread safe using go channels

Tags: go, channel

Suppose I have the following struct:

```golang
package manager

type Manager struct {
    strings []string
}

func (m *Manager) AddString(s string) {
    m.strings = append(m.strings, s)
}

func (m *Manager) RemoveString(s string) {
    for i, str := range m.strings {
        if str == s {
            m.strings = append(m.strings[:i], m.strings[i+1:]...)
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern is not thread safe, so the following test fails due to some race condition (array index out of bounds):

```
func TestManagerConcurrently(t *testing.T) {
    m := &manager.Manager{}
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i:=0; i<100; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func () {
            m.AddString("a")
            m.AddString("b")
            m.AddString("c")
            m.RemoveString("b")
            wg.Done()
        } ()
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

I'm new to Go, and from googling around I suppose I should use channels (?). So one way to make this concurrent would be like this:

```golang
type ManagerA struct {
    Manager
    addStringChan chan string
    removeStringChan chan string
}

func NewManagerA() *ManagerA {
    ma := &ManagerA{
        addStringChan: make(chan string),
        removeStringChan: make(chan string),
    }
    go func () {
        for {
            select {
            case msg := <-ma.addStringChan:
                ma.AddString(msg)
            case msg := <-ma.removeStringChan:
                ma.RemoveString(msg)
            }
        }
    }()
    return ma
}

func (m* ManagerA) AddStringA(s string) {
    m.addStringChan <- s
}
func (m* ManagerA) RemoveStringA(s string) {
    m.removeStringChan <- s
}
```

I would like to expose an API similar to the non-concurrent example, hence AddStringA, RemoveStringA.

This seems to work as expected concurrently (although I guess the inner goroutine should also exit at some point). My problem with this is that there is a lot of extra boilerplate:

- need to define & initialize channels
- define inner goroutine loop with select
- map functions to channel calls

It seems a bit much to me. Is there a way to simplify this (refactor / syntax / library)?

I think the best way to implement this would be to use a Mutex instead? But is it still possible to simplify this sort of boilerplate?

Comment: You can't "make a struct thread safe" using channels. That's not what channels do. Channels provide for thread-safe communication between goroutines. If you have two or more goroutines that need to pass messages, channels are the way to go. If you can refactor your application so that you can communicate over channels *instead of* sharing references to an object, *that* would make it thread safe. This is the Go idiom of "share memory by communicating instead of communicating by sharing memory".

Answer (score 8):

Using a mutex would be perfectly idiomatic like this:

```
type Manager struct {
    mu      sync.Mutex
    strings []string
}

func (m *Manager) AddString(s string) {
    m.mu.Lock()
    m.strings = append(m.strings, s)
    m.mu.Unlock()
}

func (m *Manager) RemoveString(s string) {
    m.mu.Lock()
    for i, str := range m.strings {
        if str == s {
            m.strings = append(m.strings[:i], m.strings[i+1:]...)
        }
    }
    m.mu.Unlock()
}
```

You could do this with channels, but as you noted it is a lot of extra work for not much gain.  Just use a mutex is my advice!

Answer (score 5):

If you simply need to make the access to the struct thread-safe, use mutex:

```
type Manager struct {
   sync.Mutex
   data []string
}

func (m *Manager) AddString(s string) {
    m.Lock()
    m.strings = append(m.strings, s)
    m.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: I would recommend against embedding `sync.Mutex` like that. Instead, add it as an unexported field.

Comment: @TimCooper: embedding a mutex value is extremely common when you need to expose the lock methods, and generally quite safe (though not technically necessary in this case). Any accidental copying of the unexported field is caught by `go vet`, which is run with all tests. (You can of course choose to not do this yourself)

Comment: It probably makes sense to hide the lock if the struct is opaque.